# SQL query to Get amount of days off in a period

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent, mariadb

Please help me write a Sql query or using Eloquent to get the vehicles and the amount of days off in a given period.

Vehicles Table:

```
|id |name     |
|---|---------|
| 1 | Truck   |
| 2 | Crane   |
```

Days off Table:

```
| vehicle_id| day_num|
| ----------|--------|
| 1         |5       | //Friday
| 1         |6       | //Saturday
| 2         |3       | //Wednesday
| 2         |4       | //Thursday
```

Example.
Request period: 02-03-2021 -  19-03-2021

The period is entered by the user and he expects to receive the amount of days off the vehicle in this period

Expected Result:

```
id:1
days_off_amount: 5 
id:2
days_off_amount:6
```

Comment: Hi, where is the code you have so far ?

Comment: need to explain how is called the column where you need to search the period range

Comment: The period is entered by the user and he expects to receive the amount of days off the vehicle in this period.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My recommendation is to do this in SQL.  Start by generating all the days you want during the period -- this is easily done using a recursive CTE.

Then use a `LEFT JOIN` and aggregation to count the days that don't match:

```
with recursive dates as (
      select date('2021-03-01') as date
      union all
      select date + interval 1 day
      from dates
      where date < '2021-03-19'
     )
select v.id, v.name, sum(doff.vehicle_id is not null) as num_days
from vehicles v cross join
     dates d left join
     daysoff doff
     on doff.vehicle_id = v.id and
        weekday(d.date) = day_num - 1
group by v.id, v.name;
```

Note:  It is unclear what your day numbering is.  You want either `weekday()` or `dayofweek()`, depending on wether weeks start on Sunday or Monday.  So you might need to tweak the example.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=b1389b69e32b96b429a6ad83fc2ac71e) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: I change sum(doff.vehicle_id is null) to sum(doff.vehicle_id is not null) and got the right solution!

Comment: Is it possible to modify this request to the database and find out the final working date? For example: vehicle is required for 2021-03-10 for 30 days, but there are days off during the period. Is it possible to get in the request the final date when the vehicle will work all 30 days, taking into account the weekend?

Comment: @Nikolay . . . I suspect that something like `max(case when doff.vehicle_id is null then d.date end)` does what you want.

Comment: It seems to me that we need a cycle in the sql query in which we will iterate over the working days until we get the necessary end dates. I do not have an end date, but I have the required working days. I need to add all the weekends that come along the way. What might this cycle look like? Thank.

Comment: @Nikolay . . . You might want to ask another question, with a clear explanation and sample data.

Answer (score 0):

Does this show the full tables? Assuming so, you cannot do this. If you want to filter the data by full dates, you will need to record the full date of each day off. Your current days off table has the day of week, but not the day of month or year, so you simply don't have the information to compare it to. Replacing 'day_of_week' with a column of type date called 'day_off_at' would accomplish this.

You would then need to update the part of the application which writes to this table to send the full date in a format mysql can understand, such as '2021-03-30', and will then have date fields you can query against, such as 'select * from days_off where day_off_at > '2021-02-01' and day_off_at < '2021-02-14'.